# Is there a way to shorten the excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I'm looking for a way to shorten my formula. I'm new to excel and have no idea how I could shorten the formula, I've made several attempts but always get errors. I'm sure for someone more experienced it will be a trivial question.

I hope someone can help me, I appreciate any response.

```
=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",$P$9:$U$11)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press",$P$9:$U$11)));V9:V11*$W$9:$W$11,0))+SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",$P$19:$U$21)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press ";$P$19:$U$21)));V19:V21*$W$19:$W$21;0))+SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",$P$29:$U$31)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press",$P$29:$U$31)));V29:V31*$W$29:$W$31,0))+SUM(IF( (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",$P$39:$U$41)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press",$P$39:$U$41)));V39:V41*$W$39:$ W$41;0))
```

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function with `MMULT()` or `BYROW()` with `VSTACK()` may shorten your long formula. Show some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (ISNUMBER(MATCH(MODE(ROW($P$9:$U$41),10);{9;0;1};0)))*
    ((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench";$P$9:$U$41)))+
    (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press";$P$9:$U$41))));
    $V$9:$V$41;
    $W$9:$W$41)
```

This allows the full range to be entered and it will only look at those rows that end in 9,0, or 1.

Comment: Nice approach! With all these new functions I sometimes forget what the older could already

Comment: @P.b I *totally agree*…  it’s getting harder and harder to solve a problem “the old way” because “the new way” has become so deeply engrained in my thinking.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any "easy" savings here.  What I do is I "decompose" a wildly complex formula in a way that helps me visualize the logic better.  In this case:

```
=SUM( IF( 
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Bench" , $P$9:$U$11 ) ) ) +
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Press" , $P$9:$U$11 ) ) ) ;
    V9:V11 * $W$9:$W$11 , 
    0 ) )

+SUM( IF(
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Bench" , $P$19:$U$21 ) ) ) +
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Press" ; $P$19:$U$21 ) ) ) ;
    V19:V21 * $W$19:$W$21 ;
    0 ) )

+SUM( IF(
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Bench" , $P$29:$U$31 ) ) ) +
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Press" , $P$29:$U$31 ) ) ) ;
    V29:V31 * $W$29:$W$31 ,
    0 ) )

+SUM( IF(
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Bench" , $P$39:$U$41 ) ) ) +
    (ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "Press" , $P$39:$U$41 ) ) ) ;
    V39:V41 * $W$39:$W$41;
    0 ) )
```

I didn't change anything except to format it in a way that lets me see the pattern...  And I want to work on patterns, not on specifics.

What I can see is this formula searches 4 ranges of 6r x 3c ranges for any instance of either "Bench" or "Press".  If there is at least one instance, multiply 2 3-cell arrays and sum the result, otherwise return zero for that range.

You have O365, so you *can* create a named LAMBDA() function in your name manager.  For instance you could create a custom Excel function in the name manager like:

`=snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$39:$U$41 )`

which would simplify each of the 4 terms to:

```
+SUM( IF( snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$39:$U$41 ), 
    V39:V41 * $W$39:$W$41; 0 ) )
```

You could go step further and encapsulate the whole SUM(IF()) to be a function:

`=snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$39:$U$41, V39:V41, $W$39:$W$41 )`

In which case your WHOLE formula becomes:

```
= snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$9:$U$11 , V9:V11 , $W$9:$W$11  ) +
  snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$19:$U$21, V19:V21, $W$19:$W$21 ) +
  snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$29:$U$31, V29:V31, $W$29:$W$31 ) +
  snorlaxFunction( "Bench", "Press", $P$39:$U$41, V39:V41, $W$39:$W$41 )
```

Honestly, if it was me...  I don't see any easy way to shorten the logic, and I don't have repeated terms that are good candidates for a LET() function.  So I'd leave the formula as-is but use `alt` `enters` to present the formula in outline format like I did above.  I wouldn't go through the work to create named LAMBDA()s for this unless I was going to be reusing the formula many times in the spreadsheet.

**NOTE**

One thing I noticed is your notation drifts a lot between `comma` delimited and `semicolon` delimited text, as you can see above.  I would stick to your configured regional setting and be 100% consistent, using *only* commas or semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LET` and stacking the ranges you can simplify your formula:

```
=LET(pu,VSTACK($P$9:$U$11,$P$19:$U$21,$P$29:$U$31,$P$39:$U$41),
     v, VSTACK(V9:V11,V19:V21,V29:V31,V39:V41),
     w, VSTACK($W$9:$W$11,$W$19:$W$21,$W$29:$W$31,$W$39:$W$41),

SUM(IF(
       (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",pu)))+
       (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press",pu))),
       v*w,
       0)))
```

And as suggested by Scott Craner you could start with the range covering all columns/rows and filter out the ranges to be used. That way, if data may grow, you only need to adjust the first `LET` condition to have the formula adjusted:

```
=LET(rng,P9:W41,
     pw,FILTER(rng,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(MOD(ROW(rng),10),{9;0;1}))),
     pu,TAKE(pw,,COLUMNS(pw)-2),
     v,  CHOOSECOLS(pw,COLUMNS(pw)-1),
     w, TAKE(pw,,-1),
SUM(IF(
       (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("bench",pu)))+ 
       (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("press",pu))),
       v*w,
       0)))
```

Comment: I thought about stacking like this but I think it breaks the logic.  Your approach is all-or-nothing;  In the original formula, if there was a match in the first range, but not in the other 3 ranges, the result would be `v * x` *of the first range.*  Your approach provides the sum of all 4 ranges even if there’s a match in only 1, 2, or 3 ranges.  That’s a different logical result.

Comment: @MaxR I couldn't reproduce an example where the original formula would result differently than the version stacking the ranges. It creates a product of v*w at the row where either `bench` or `press` is found times the number of times it is found.

Comment: @P.b I don’t see where a row-wise computation occurs in your solution.  Your formula says “If the word “Bench” or “Press” occurs one or more times *anywhere* in the combined ranges, then multiply all of matrix V with all of matrix W, and then sum it.  Neither the count of occurrences of “Bench” or “Press” are material to the sum.  All that matters is that if there is one or more instances, then execute and return the sum.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: You, sir/ma'am have outsmarted me.  When I read `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bench",pu)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Press",pu)))` I thought "that can't work, that will resolve to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Always up for some discovery, I tried it and it instantly dawned on me that the result is an *array* of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s.